# I-Nex (trouble installing)

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

I cant install `i-nex` for the following reason:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 i-nex : Depends: gambas3-runtime (>= 3.5.0) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: gambas3-gb-image (>= 3.5.0) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: gambas3-gb-qt4 (>= 3.5.0) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: gambas3-gb-form (>= 3.5.0) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: gambas3-gb-desktop (>= 3.5.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `libcpuid11` and `Gambas Stable Builds` PPA's to your system

add `libcpuid11` PPA by running this command

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:i-nex-development-team/libcpuid11
```

add `Gambas Stable Builds` PPA by running this command

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gambas-team/gambas3
```

Then install `i-nex`

```
sudo apt-get install i-nex
```

if it shows this output at the end of the install

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 i-nex
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

delete the install script. Run this command

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/i-nex.postinst
```

and run the install command again

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

then run i-nex

```
i-nex
```

[image]

Comment: Additionally I had to do "sudo add-apt-repository ppa:i-nex-development-team/daily"